# How to make disabled form fields printed with more contrast with Angular

Tags: css, angular

Our application allow the user to print the form he submitted. Disabled fields aren't printed dark enough though.

I was able to make a lot of fields print black but I can't get the radio button text and drop down field value to print dark black. Only the radio button circle and drop down label are printed black.

Is there a trick to do that more easily? How can I cover those 2 elements with CSS?

EDIT: the solution already use theme. When I look at the color computed CSS in Chrome I see that the CSS I try to apply gets bumped in the 3rd place. I can't find the way to prioritize the @media print part of my CSS.
[Chrome computed CSS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvM4s.png)

```
  @media print {
    input {
      color: black !important;
    }

    ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element {
      background-color: black !important;
    }
    
    ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
      background-color: black !important;   /*inner circle color change*/
    }
    
    ::ng-deep .mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-outer-circle {
     border-color:black !important; /*outer ring color change*/
    }
    
    textarea {
      color: black !important;
    }

    label {
      color: black !important;
    }

    mat-label {
      color: black !important;
    }

    span {
      color: black !important;
    }

    div  {
      color: black !important;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What type of select are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I added this. It works.

```css
::ng-deep.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked
  .mat-radio-outer-circle {
  border-color: #000000 !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle,
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent
  .mat-radio-ripple
  .mat-ripple-element:not(.mat-radio-persistent-ripple),
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked .mat-radio-persistent-ripple,
.mat-radio-button.mat-accent:active .mat-radio-persistent-ripple {
  background-color: #555555 !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-radio-button.mat-accent.mat-radio-checked
  .mat-radio-persistent-ripple {
  background-color: #333333 !important;
}

::ng-deep.mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-ripple .mat-ripple-element:not(.mat-radio-persistent-ripple) {
  background-color: #333333 !important;
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tld6yn-uhgtkn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.css

Better alternative would be to use theming but for not, this works.

Comment: The solution already use a theme and I thing the problem if that the theme CSS is taken as higher priority than what I try to do. I'll put more information in my question.